# How to remove files on server on import backup with all-in-one-wp-migration?

Tags: wordpress, backup

i am using vite in wordpress.
When i work in local, made a build and generat js and css file with hash.
After upload backup to server the files in dist/ map is not removed.
And at the end i have a lot of js and css files with hash.
Can i remove files in dist before import backup?

Thanks in advance